# Gatsby fails creating Contentful pages in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-source-contentful

I am trying to create **Contentful** dynamic pages in **Gatsby + Typescript**. Right now, I am able to fetch data while using GraphQL in a browser. The problem arises when I try to fetch data in `gatsby-node.ts`. It seems the pages are being generated but not completely. Also, I get this error:

> ERROR #12100  API.TYPESCRIPT.TYPEGEN
>
> There was an error while trying to generate TS types from your GraphQL
> queries:
>
> ```
> Error: GraphQL Document Validation failed with 1 errors;   Error 0: This anonymous operation must be the only defined operation.
> at /home/ugnius/GIT/New-webpage/gatsby-node.ts:1:1
> ```
>
> See our docs page for more info on this error:
> https://gatsby.dev/graphql-typegen
>
> failed Generating GraphQL and TypeScript types - 0.109s

**gatsby-node.ts**

```js
import type { GatsbyNode } from 'gatsby';
import * as path from 'path';

export const createPages: GatsbyNode['createPages'] = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const request = await graphql<Queries.Query>(`
    {
      allContentfulInsight {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const insightTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/Insight.tsx');
  const insights = request?.data?.allContentfulInsight.edges;

  insights?.forEach((insight, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `insights/${insight.node.slug}`,
      component: insightTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: insight.node.slug,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

**src/templates/Insight.tsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const InsightTemplate: React.FC<Queries.InsightBySlugQuery> = (data) => {
  const title = data?.contentfulInsight?.title; // => undefined
  console.log(data); // prints correct data from Contentful but it is undefined in code

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default InsightTemplate;

export const query = graphql`
  query InsightBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    contentfulInsight(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      content {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**gatsby-types.dts**

```js
declare namespace Queries {
  // ...
  type Query = {
    readonly allContentfulInsight: ContentfulInsightConnection;
    // ...
  };
  // ...
  type ContentfulInsightConnection = {
    readonly edges: ReadonlyArray<ContentfulInsightEdge>;
    // ...
  };
  // ...
  type ContentfulInsightEdge = {
    readonly node: ContentfulInsight;
    // ...
  };
  // ...
  type ContentfulInsight = ContentfulEntry & ContentfulReference & Node & {
    readonly slug: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    readonly title: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    readonly content: Maybe<ContentfulInsightContent>;
    // ...
  };
  // ...
  type InsightBySlugQueryVariables = Exact<{
    slug: Scalars['String'];
  }>;

  type InsightBySlugQuery = {
    readonly site: { readonly siteMetadata: { readonly title: string | null } | null } | null;
    readonly contentfulInsight: {
      readonly title: string | null;
      readonly content: { readonly raw: string | null } | null;
    } | null;
  };
}
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix `ERROR #12100 API.TYPESCRIPT.TYPEGEN`, you need to change GraphQL query in `gatsby-node.ts` from

```
const request = await graphql<Queries.Query>(`
  query AllInsights {
    allContentfulInsight {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

to

```js
const request = await graphql<Queries.Query>(`
  {
    allContentfulInsight {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

To fix `Insight.tsx` you need properly describe template props:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

interface InsightTemplateProps {
  data: {
    site: {
      siteMetadata: { title: string };
    };
    contentfulInsight: {
      title: string;
      content: { raw: string };
    };
  };
}

const InsightTemplate: React.FC<InsightTemplateProps> = ({ data }) => {
  const title = data.contentfulInsight.title;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
export default InsightTemplate;

export const query = graphql`
  query InsightBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    contentfulInsight(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      content {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
`;
```